# "Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START at [16], field=add" adding record to Solr via cURL

Tags: php, json, curl, solr

Based on the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174999/add-document-to-apache-solr-via-php-curl) (and other places), I am attempting to add a record to a simple Solr index (the only fields are `src` and `dest`, both single value string fields, and solrconfig is set to auto generate the `id` value) via PHP and cURL using the following code:

```
$data = array(
  "add" => array(
    "doc" => array(
      "src" => $src,
      "dest" => $dest
    ),
    "commitWithin" => 1000,
  ),
);

$data_string = json_encode(array($data));
$add_url = 'https://my-solr-url.com/solr/my_index/update?commit=true&wt=json';
$add_ch = curl_init($add_url);
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$add_response = json_decode(curl_exec($add_ch));
curl_close($add_ch);
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START at [16], field=add
```

Based on the [Solr docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#adding-a-single-json-document), I tried the following variation:

```
$data = array(
  'src' => $src,
  'dest' => $dest
);

$data_string = json_encode(array($data));
$add_url = 'https://my-solr-url.com/solr/my_index/update/json/docs?commit=true&wt=json';
$add_ch = curl_init($add_url);
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($add_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$add_response = json_decode(curl_exec($add_ch));
curl_close($add_ch);
```

But now I get an error about `Unknown field src`. From what I can see, Im following the docs, but nothing works. What do I need to change?

Comment: why do you encode `aray($data)` instead of simply `$data` ?

Comment: Because it is a PHP array (this is PHP code), and the data needs to be in json format in the URL.

Comment: But as @YvesLeBorg asked, why `$data_string = json_encode(array($data));` ... ? Just do `$data_string = json_encode($data);`

Comment: Oh. thanks, @IncredibleHat, I see what you're saying. That did the trick. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was that I was creating a double array:

```
$data = array(
  "add" => array(
    "doc" => array(
      "src" => $src,
      "dest" => $dest
    ),
    "commitWithin" => 1000,
  ),
);

$data_string = json_encode(array($data));
```

Once I changed the last line to

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

it worked fine.